# redirect old product links to new prestashop product links

Tags: redirect, prestashop

I have transferred a old webshop to prestashop.
The products have the same ID´s.

The old link look like this:
/shopexd.asp?id=2760&bc=no

And the new one like this.

/da/mover/2760-truma-mover-sr.html

Is it possible to redirect to the new product links? By modifying the .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using apache as webserver.

Try something like that and add:

```
RewriteRule ^shopexd.asp?id=([0-9]+)&(.*)$ /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you updated from 1.2 to 1.6 as example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)?id_product=(\d+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ /index.php?id_product=%2&controller=product [R=301,L]
```