# where to redirect old prestashop urls?

Tags: redirect, prestashop-1.6

Hello could somebody please tell me where to redirect urls of old removed products from prestashop 1.6.0.9?

Is it right to redirect them to 404 page or to homepage? (whats better?)

AND HOW TO REDIRECT IT?

Actually when I type link of removed product to browser it redirects me to custom page of my website but just with warning in red rectangle:

1 error
1. Product not found

(see the attachment in link)
http://s11.postimg.org/wm2ho4b2b/image.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect old product links to new prestashop product links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955234/redirect-old-product-links-to-new-prestashop-product-links)

Answer (score 0):

I think you had to use a 301 redirect. modify/create a htaccess file like this:

//redirect from URL to other
RewriteRule /old_url_of_product.html http://www.homepage_website.com/ [R=301]

First parameter are the old url, next are the new url.
This is the best way for SEO.